# Вставка в поле числа из определенного диапазона

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Не могу в запросе вставить информацию!
Существует в Бд поле `kod_oper`. Мне нужно вставить в это числовое поле! В нём есть информация и мне надо вставить числа в диапазоне от `42201` до `42299`. Что то не получается! Надеюсь, понятно объяснил)

```
$mysql_query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO s_vpoper (kod_oper,name_oper)
          VALUES ('".$arr[$i][1]."','".$arr[$i][2]."') WHERE kod_oper > '42201' AND kod_oper <'42299'");
```

**UPD:**
Мне нужно в поле `kof_oper` вставить числа! В этой ячейке есть числа от 1000, 1001, 1002 и тд! Мне нужно вставить числа между 42201 и 42299!

Comment: структуру таблицы, и вопрос с примером что нада вставить и кула, а то из вашего вопроса я ничего не понял(

Answer (score 2):

Это немного на бред похоже, я с трудом прочитал.

Вставить в таблицу а тут еще и where синтаксис INSERT видел хоть раз?

```
 INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED] [IGNORE]
        [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
        VALUES (expression,...),(...),...
        [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_name=expression, ... ]
или INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED] [IGNORE]
        [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
        SELECT ...
или INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED] [IGNORE]
        [INTO] tbl_name
        SET col_name=(expression | DEFAULT), ...
        [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_name=expression, ... ]
```

Если обновить записи то UPDATE

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] tbl_name
    SET col_name1=expr1 [, col_name2=expr2 ...]
    [WHERE where_definition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT rows]
или
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] tbl_name [, tbl_name ...]
    SET col_name1=expr1 [, col_name2=expr2 ...]
    [WHERE where_definition]
```

И вот тут можно юзать **WHERE**

Нормально переформулировать вопрос нужно. куда вставляем, зачем, почему там есть where для чего, структуру таблицы... чем больше информации тем лучше ответ.

**//UPD** 
Полный идиотизм!
Зачем так делать?
Код у тебя будет такой, иначе я не знаю как сделать, но тут может возникнуть ошибка если в таблице нет $num значения + ко всей этой бредни значения будут постоянно переписываться т.к. используется рандом.

В общем задача вообще не понятна.
Напиши что это, для чего и зачем. Иначе реально просто бредня какая-то.

```
$num=rand(42201 ,42299);
$sql="UPDATE s_vpoper  set kod_oper='".$arr[$i][1]."',name_oper='".$arr[$i][2]." where kod_oper='".$num."';
```

**//upd2**

> Да нет это я просто написал where! что
> вы поняли а вы не поняли)

Я задал вопрос, ну не совсем вопрос, точнее даже не вопрос, а может и вопрос но все написал просто так чтобы вы поняли, или не поняли, в общем посмотрите что я тут наделал.

Ну не бред ли а?

Comment: Да нет это я просто написал where! что вы поняли а вы не поняли) смотрите! нужно мне в поле kof_oper вставить числа! в этой ячейке есть числа  от 1000, 1001, 1002 и тд! мне нужно вставить числа между  42201 и 42299!

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятен запрос. Тут, извините, чушь. Вы хотите вставить в таблицу s_vpoper ряд где существует ряд о kod_oeper>42201 и <42299. Давайте подойдём более детаьно:

1. Ваша штучка выполняется в цикле. Хмм. Где этот цикл?
2. Ваш запрос неправилен. Тут проблема в истоках - смотрите синтаксис INSERT INTO.
3. Вы, цитирую, хотите вставить запись в БД, а не в таблицу, находящуюся в БД.
4. Самое простое решение

   ```
   $from = 42201;
   $to = 42299;
   for($k=from;$i<=to;$i++){
       $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO s_vpoper(kod_oper, name_oper) VALUES ({$i}, {arr[$i][2]})");//Не совсем понимаю как выглядит остальной код поэтому так оставил
       ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

А про

```
if (!$mysql_query) die ("Ошибка в " . mysql_error());
```

Никто не слышал?

`p.s.`

**mysql_error** — Returns the text of the error message from previous MySQL operation